# How should I write a 2nd interval between two voices?

Tags: notation

I've written two voices, and as you can see here, they are seperated by a 2nd, so the notes intersect. This is, obviously, unacceptable.

[image]

So how should I handle this? If I move the note heads, it looks a little weird to me.

[image]

I'm using MuseScore for my notation software.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The lowest notes on these examples must be written on the right of the chord. Not on the left or vertically centered as shown above.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! For people viewing this question in the future, I figured out how to do it in MuseScore: double-click on the note and press the right arrow key.

Comment: See also the pamphlet [Standard Music Notation Practice](https://www.mpa.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/standard-practice-engraving.pdf), page 7, rules (e) and (f), by the Music Publishers' Association.